# Standing up for an older person or Talmid Chacham who is already sitting down

Tags: halacha, age, standing-sitting, kavod, yoreh-deah

When an older person or Talmid Chacham walks into a place where you are sitting, you must stand up for them (or least "rise" a little from one's seat.) - see Yoreh Deah 244:1. If someone was sitting in a room and noticed that there was an older person now sitting in the room as well that wasn't there before. Presumably they had just walked in and the person didn't notice.

Must the one sitting now stand up or rise a little in order to honor this older person that had previously walked into the room, but is currently sitting down?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/honouring-an-older-person (Honoring an older person)

Comment: If a person is over seventy then only someone under seventy has to stand up for him. That is how one can tell how old a person is. (if the knows this din).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 244:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.244.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it would seem that one doesn't have to get up.

The shulchan Aruch writes

> אסור להעצים עיניו ממנו קודם שיגיע לתוך ארבע אמותיו כדי שלא יצטרך לקום מפניו כשיגיע לתוך ארבע אמותיו

Meaning, that if you know that someone you have to get up for will be walking by soon, do not close your eyes to avoid seeing him and as such absolve yourself from the duty of standing up.

We can derive from this that if you did close your eyes you are Patur from standing up, even though if the Chacham is only outside your 4 Amos.